# Алгоритм для автокомплита

Tags: javascript, html, алгоритм

Есть необходимость создать автокомплит. Вводишь значение в *input*, дальше он сравнивает его с первыми буквами значений из массива строк, допустим языков программирования. На выходе в *div* должен создавать список со значениями из массива данных в которых есть совпадение с введеным в *input* значением. Сравнение производится по первым буквам. Пытался решить эту задачу топорно и напрямую, просто выводить все значения и скрывать непроходящие проверку, и с каждым новым символом введеным в *input* просто прогонять все это заново по всему списку. Дак вот, как реализовать оптимизированный легкий алгоритм поиска совпадений в строках, при условии, что в *input* могут добавлять символы, так и удалять их. Любая информация будет полезна. Язык - чистый *javascript*

```js
function visibility() {

var div = doc.getElementById("myDropdown");
var input = doc.getElementById("myInput").value;

if (input.length >= 1) {
    div.style.display = "block";
} else {
    div.style.display = "none"; 
}
}
function filterFunction() {

  var input = doc.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var div = doc.getElementById("myDropdown");
  var a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) {
      a[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: "Segoe";
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#myInput:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 360px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 360px;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #494949;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите язык программирования" id="myInput" onkeyup="visibility(); filterFunction()" autocomplete="off">

<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
</div>
```

Comment: Рады будем увидеть Ваше решение. Пока это только ТЗ без ценника.

Comment: 1) Выводим весь список в наш блок
2) Прогоняем весь массив на совпадение с каждым новым символом
`
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) {
            a[i].style.display = "block";
            check++; 
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }`

Comment: 1) Обновления вопроса добавляйте в него же. 2) Создайте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Other я человек новый на этом сайте, поэтому как смог вставил, сильно не ругайтесь

Comment: Уже гораздо лучше, только функцию `visibility` забыли вставить.

Comment: @Other вроде добавил

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь - https://learn.javascript.ru/string#поиск-всех-вхождений

Comment: Вот вам еще пример - https://github.com/Pixabay/JavaScript-autoComplete

Comment: А вот, собственно, демо - https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html

Comment: @Astor спасибо большое, оказалось полезным